# Im getting an Undefined Control Sequence with BibTex

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, errors

I made this work again, the undefined control sequence with `\begin` was because my old file was somehow corrupted I think. I copied the main files and switched to biber. Now my setup is finally working again.

This is my code in the main file:

```
\listfiles
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{exsheets}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[backend=biber,sortcites,defernumbers]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{test.bib}

\begin{document}

\SetupExSheets{
  question/type = exam ,
  headings = klausur,
  solution/print = true,
  counter-within=section
}

\let\oldsolution\solution

\renewenvironment{solution}{%
    \SetupExSheets{counter-format=}
    \oldsolution
}

\begin{titlepage}
  \centering
  \Huge Theoriepr"ufung DSV-Skilehrer \par
  \vspace{3cm}
  \normalsize
  BLABLA.\\
\end{titlepage}

\tableofcontents
\newpage
BLABLA \citetitle{theorie}.
\newpage 
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

And my bib File:

```
@book{theorie,
author = {Behnke, S. and Braun, T.},
title = {DSV - Theorielehrbuch},
publisher = {Deutscher Skiverband Verlag},
address = {Planegg},
year = {2013} }
```

What stopped me from solving this earlier is that my Texmaker was configured to use bibtex. Now I got it back to work, still don't know why I'm getting `! Undefined control sequence.
\entry` in my old document. I'm fine with it working again like this however.

Comment: Please, make a self-contained example producing the error; we don't have your files.

Comment: With an current MiKTeX 2.9 I can compile your code without errors ... Please add comand `\listfiles` as first line to your MWE and compile three times.  Then check the `log` file at the end and copy the resulting list of used packages and version numbers to your question.  Which TeX distribution do you use? Version number?

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem with the MWE you posted on a fairly up-to-date MikTeX distribution. Make sure your packages are really up to date, delete the temporary files and try again. Check that you don't have `biblatex` installed twice. If you use MikTeX update in both User and Admin mode.

Comment: Indeed, your packages seem to be up to date. The `.log`, however, does not come from the MWE you posted. Please make sure to post an [actual MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864), i.e. a file that reproduces the problem, can be run on our computers without extra files, and is as short as possible (loads as few packages as possible).

Comment: After changing to a minimal Version, I get different errors, I actually don't know why....

Comment: Try deleting the temporary files (`.bcf`, `.aux`, `.bbl`) and try again. (You should switch from BibTeX to Biber, though, the former is only supported as a legacy backend). (The `\lossort` thingy looks to me as though `biblatex` is confused as to whether you use BibTeX or Biber.)

Comment: Any news here? The question has changed quite a lot over the time. Please update it with the current state of affairs. Which errors do you get with which example?

Comment: I'll do that by tuesday or wednesday. Can't right now, sorry.

Comment: Does your update mean your problem is solved?

Comment: Yes. I don't know why, but with this code I get no more errors. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem has been resolved by the OP themselves. The code in the question did not reproduce the issue and so the question is unanswerable.